# Split string based on Roman Numerals C#

Tags: c#

I want to Find roman numbers inside string (numbers below 20 is enough) and split the string based on roman numbers

eg:user input is :

```
Whats your name?i)My name is C# ii)My name is ROR iii)My Name is Java
```

i want to do something like

```
Whats your name?
i)My name is C# 
ii)My name is ROR 
iii)My Name is Java
```

Edit:this is to format the optional questions..so options wont go no more than 5 or 6..

Comment: Some Roman numerals can be words, e.g. `civil`. I guess you don't intend for the numbers to get that high. Will the numbers be increasing by 1 each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
string input = "I. Some text. II. Some text... V. Some stupid text. XVII. Eshe kakaya-to hernya...";

Regex r = new Regex(@"\bx{0,3}(i{1,3}|i[vx]|vi{0,3})\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string result = r.Replace(input, new MatchEvaluator(e => Environment.NewLine + e.Value)).Trim();
```

Result:

```
I. Some text. 
II. Some text... 
V. Some stupid text. 
XVII. Eshe kakaya-to hernya...
```

Comment: Note that this will fail if the text parts contains a single `i` or `v`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Regex.Split(yourstring, @"(?=\b\w+\))")
```

should do what you want.

**Example:**

```
var s = "Whats your name?i)My name is C# ii)My name is ROR iii)My Name is Java XX)foo ix)barv x)foobar";
Regex.Split(s, @"(?=\b\w+\))").Dump();
```

**Output:**

[image]

Note that you can't have a `)` in your text. You could use `(?=\b[ivxIXV]+\))` as alternative then if you want, but I think you should keep it simple.